# Linux on a Lenovo Ideapad S510P

Tags: installation, lenovo

I'm thinking of buying a Lenovo Ideapad S510P, and I want to install Ubuntu on this. I wonder if anyone has any experience with this particular laptop, and running Ubuntu on it.

Comment: If you list some of the specs, we might be able to get an idea of how it would work.

Comment: You have more than enough computing power for any Ubuntu version since it has an Intel Core i5 4200U (1.60GHz), 6GB Memory, 1TB HDD, Intel HD Graphics 4400, Touchscreen @ 1366 x 768

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work perfectly because I have a similar lenovo laptop with those specs. It runs perfectly.